# Safest way to trim a $_GET variable before file inclusion

Tags: php, include

I'm using:

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['page']; //ie: http://localhost/?page=index
include "php/{$file}.php";

?>
```

But I need to know what is the safest way to trim the `$file` variable befor calling `include`.

I was thinking about something like:

```
//-replace '.' with ''
//-replace '/' with ''
//-replace '\' with ''
```

But I'm sure there is a better way of doing, so I'm asking for your help, please.
I need it to be very secure.

Thank you.

Comment: If you know the possible pages, just make a whitelist and ignore all files that are not contained in this whitelist.

Comment: You should consider using an MVC instead for this kind of thing.  The front controller of the MVC will direct requests for different pages to the appropriate file and method, and you won't be exposing quite so much of your application.  Otherwise, the whitelist that martinstoeckli suggested above would work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to be very secure, don't include it as it comes, even after trimming. Instead, use a dicitionary-like association between the variable you get and the file you need to include:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['page'];

$allowed_pages = array('index', 'profile', 'legal', 'about');

if (in_array($file, $allowed_pages)) {
    include "php/" . $file . ".php");
} else {
    die("The page " . $file ." does not exist");
}
?>
```

This way, you will **never** get any unexpected includes.

Comment: .. and it could be upgraded, so that `$allowed_pages` is a file list from a defined directory. This way, one wouldn't need to update the code and still be on the safe side (as long as all files in that folder are allowed).

Answer (score 1):

I guess whatever you do, you can't trust user data.

If you have a limited number of avaible files, you should make an array of them and allow them.

```
$allowedFiles = array('index','somewhere','elswhere');

if (!in_array($file,$allowedFile))
    exit ('File Not found');
else
    include("php/{$file}.php");
```

EDIT:

Another way is to scan your directory and remove files and dirs you do not want.

```
$filesInDir = scandir("./php");
$allowedFiles = array_diff(array(".","..","protected.php"),$filesInDir);

if (!in_array($file.".php",$allowedFile))
    exit ('File Not found');
else
    include("php/{$file}.php");
```

Comment: Just checking if the file exists could be dangerous.  I'd vote for the whitelist

Comment: -1 for the `file_exists()` part (without that it'd be +1). Suggesting that this improves security is incredibly dangerous - it still allows including arbitrary files.

Comment: `file_exists` alone is problematic, suppose `$file` is something like `../../hiddenpasswordfile.txt`.

Comment: Even better, `../uploads/foo.jpg%00` with that "foo.jpg" file containing PHP code.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Looks interesting, what is the intention of the %00 after the filename?

Comment: It cuts off the hardcoded .php extension since C-style file functions are not binary safe regarding paths.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Ahh yes thanks, should have looked at the code more closely.